# Connecting to Nodejs/Socket.IO server with SSL (https) when listening to custom port

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

My socket.io server is running and listening to port 6060.

Now, I added to my domain an SSL certificate in order to serve my website through https protocol.

If i'm trying to access the nodejs/socket.io server through http://mydomain.com:6060 i'm getting the "Welcome to socket.io." message, but when i'm doing it with https://mydomain.com:6060 it's not work..

Is it posible to connect to my socket.io server (listening to port 6060) with ssl?

What are my options in such a case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on sockeio docs i found this:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1011

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://mysecuresite.com',{secure: true, port:6060});
```

Comment: but what about my custom port? my socket.io server is listening to port 6060

Comment: You should be able to pass that as an option as well. See my edit.